# Sequelize model only updates when I log out then log back in

Tags: sql-update, sequelize.js, put

So basically my issue is that when a user is logged in they can take a test. When the test is passed a user is given points and their level is updated using a put route. Once the put route has run the user is redirected back to their homepage where their stats are displayed. If I look in Postman after the request is made I can see the changes. However, the get route on the user's homepage is still displaying as the previous data. Only when I log out then log back in does the user object actually update on the app.

the get request is called in the document. ready function for the user's page like so...

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // This file just does a GET request to figure out which user is logged in
  // and updates the HTML on the page
  $.get("/api/user_data").then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    $(".user-name").text(data.username);
    $(".first-name").text(data.first);
    $(".last-name").text(data.last);
    $(".email").text(data.email);
    $(".xp").text(data.points);
  
  });
```

the put route is in a function that runs when the last question of the test is answered. It looks like this...

```js
function endGame() {
        console.log("END OF GAME SCORE: " + score);
        $(".quiz-container").css("display", "none");

        console.log(data.points);
        console.log(data.level);
        var addPoints = score * 100 + data.points;
        var newLevel = data.level + 1;
        

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/user_data",
            method: "PUT",
            data: {
                id: data.id,
                level: newLevel,
                point: addPoints
            },
            error: function(req, err) {
                console.log(err)
                
            },
            success: function(res, err) {
                window.location.replace("/members");
                
            }
        }).then(result => {
            
            console.log("user info updated");
            console.log(result);
            window.location.replace("/members");
        });
    }
```

As you can see the user is redirected over to the "members" page which is where the get request is sent on the document being ready. I'm pretty new so any help would be greatly appreciated.

also here is the `db.sync` method I had been working with force true and force false now i just have...

```js
db.sequelize.sync({}).then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      "==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.",
      PORT,
      PORT
    );
  });
});
```